# Opening Links from Other Apps (Firefox Containers)

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

I have the [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) extension installed.

When I click on links in other applications, for example email, is there a way to choose which container it opens on?
Right now, it opens without a container.

Comment: Somewhat related (although not what you are asking for): You cannot modify a link to open in a specific container: https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues/2361#issuecomment-1125381134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of installing yet another add-on just for this, I recommend just drag and drop. That way, if you are currently on a tab in the Personal container, the new link will be opened in that container. If you want to open in another container, while you are holding your mouse, you can press the keyboard shortcut to open a new tab in the desired container (for example, `Ctrl + Shift + 2` for "Work" container) and drop the link on the new tab.

Another way is to hold your mouse on a tab in a container that you want so that you switch to that tab and then drop the link in a new tab to open in that container.